# D3 Selecting all elements having a certain class or combination of classes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 and I want to select all elements on the page that have a certain class.  I have tried:

```
    d3.selectAll("body").attr("body", "symbol-clicked");
```

but this assigns the class symbol-clicked to all elements on the page.  I just want a collection of group of elements that already have the symbol-clicked class so I can change it to just symbol.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".className")
```

This will give you all the elements with the class 'className'.

To get elements with multiple classes. Try

```
 d3.select("body").selectAll(".className1").filter(".className2")
```